# Specify which percentage of data to be shown in a LineChart

Tags: java, javafx, linechart

Is there a way to specify how much (in percentage) of the data should be shown on a LineChart in JavaFX? For the x axis I can just add less data to the LineChart, but how would this work for the y axis?

Thank you,
Matthias

Comment: So, you're trying to cut of the top of your graph?

Comment: Yes, just found the solution myself. For people who have the same problem in the future, disable autoRanging, cast your Axis to a NumberAxis and calculate the upper bound (max y value * a certain percentage).